# How to improve performance for imbalanced dataset using SVM

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm

I am trying to classify data at the token-level using scikit-learn.  I already have a `train` and `test` split.
The data is in the following `\t` seperated format:

```
-----------------
token       label
-----------------
way          6
to           6
reduce       6
the          6
amount       6
of           6
traffic      6
   ....
public       2
transport    5
is           5
a            5
key          5
factor       5
to           5 
minimize     5
   ....
```

The data is distributes as follows:

```
                              Training Data                    Test Data
# Total:                        119490                          29699
# Class 0:                      52631                           13490
# Class 1:                      35116                           8625
# Class 2:                      17968                           4161
# Class 3:                      8658                            2088
# Class 4:                      3002                            800
# Class 5:                      1201                            302
# Class 6:                      592                             153
```

I'm trying `SVM` and  the `F1-score` is pretty bad.

The code is:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfTransformer
from sklearn.linear_model import SGDClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score, f1_score
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # reading Files
    train_df = pd.read_csv(TRAINING_DATA_PATH, names=['token', 'label'], sep='\t')
    test_df = pd.read_csv(TEST_DATA_PATH, names=['token', 'label'], sep='\t')

    # getting training and testing data
    train_X = train_df['token'].astype('U')
    test_X = test_df['token'].astype('U')
    train_y = train_df['label']
    test_y = test_df['label']

    # Linear SVM
    sgd = Pipeline([('vect', CountVectorizer()),        
                    ('tfidf', TfidfTransformer()),      
                    ('clf',   SGDClassifier(loss='hinge', penalty='l2', alpha=1e-3, max_iter=100, tol=None)
                   ])
    f1_list = []
    acc_list = []
    cv = KFold(n_splits=5)
    for train_index, test_index in cv.split(train_X):
        X_train, X_val = train_X[train_index], train_X[test_index]
        y_train, y_val = train_y[train_index], train_y[test_index]
        sgd.fit(X_train, y_train)
        predicted = sgd.predict(X_val)
        f1 = f1_score(y_val, predicted, average='macro')
        acc = accuracy_score(y_val, predicted)
        f1_list.append(f1)
        acc_list.append(acc)
    print(f1_list)
    print(acc_list)
    sgd_pred = sgd.predict(test_X)
    print('SVM accuracy: %s' % accuracy_score(sgd_pred, test_y))
    print('SVM F1-macro: %s' % f1_score(sgd_pred, test_y, average='macro'))
    print('SVM F1-weighted: %s' % f1_score(sgd_pred, test_y, average='weighted'))
```

The results for the Linear SVM is as follows:

```
SVM accuracy: 0.49493248930940437
SVM F1-macro: 0.2677988484198396
```

How do I improve the performace?

Answer (score 0):

There are several measures you can consider to improve your predictive performance:

1. Use the `class_weight` parameter to penalize errors on minority classes heavier

   ```
   sgd = Pipeline([('vect', CountVectorizer()),        
                 ('tfidf', TfidfTransformer()),      
                 ('clf',   SGDClassifier(loss='hinge', 
                                         penalty='l2',
                                         class_weight='balanced', # add this
                                         alpha=1e-3, 
                                         max_iter=100, 
                                         tol=None)
              ])
   ```
2. Resample your data before training with the [`imblearn`](https://imbalanced-learn.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html) library, e.g.

   ```
   from imblearn.oversampling import SMOTE

   # getting training and testing data
   train_X = train_df['token'].astype('U')
   test_X = test_df['token'].astype('U')
   train_y = train_df['label']
   test_y = test_df['label']

   sm = SMOTE(random_state=42)
   train_X_res, train_y_res = sm.fit_resample(train_X, train_y)
   ```
3. Try another classifier, e.g. `Logistic Regression`

   ```
   sgd = Pipeline([('vect', CountVectorizer()),        
                 ('tfidf', TfidfTransformer()),      
                 ('clf',   SGDClassifier(loss='log', # change here
                                         penalty='l2',
                                         alpha=1e-3, 
                                         max_iter=100, 
                                         tol=None)
   ```

You can try these things all separately or in combination. But especially the first two are the classic measures to deal with imbalanced data sets.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried all 3 things separately and in combination, but the results unfortunately are no different. I guess since the data is at token level and each word can appear in all the classes there isn't much for the models to learn until it somehow also learns the context. In my dataset words belonging to one class appear in batches, e.g the first 10 words could belong to class0 , the next 7 to class1 and so on. So I was thinking of trying to collect n-grams but am not sure how that will work as the test data is to be fitted at the token level again.